# Rename columns in SQL Server from any name to a new one

Tags: sql

I need to know how to rename a SQL table column from any name. I can use the following code if I know the current name.

```
    sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

But if I don't know the column name, how can I change it to a new one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't know the column name then what other information about the column do you know that identifies the column?

Comment: I think you shouldn't touch this table.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I know the column number...

Comment: If you don't know the column name and all the places where it is refernced, then you should not be doing this. If you want to look up column name in the sys tables to change them, then your design is flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know column number (ordinal position) you can get column name by running following query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<TableName>' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = <ColumnNumber>
```

Here is a possible example of use

```
DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(128)

SELECT @ColName = COLUMN_NAME FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 6

SET @ColName = 'TableName.[' + @ColName + ']'

sp_RENAME @ColName , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Where should I add the new name of the column in above code?

Comment: I've added a possible example of use to my answer. Note, I haven't tested the code, so syntax may need some adjustments

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Please mark the answer as accepted if results are to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

be very careful with this though, as altering a table may cause unforseen consequences, if stored procedures, triggers, etc call the columns explicitly by name, they will no longer function correctly.